# JSONModel type not allowed error with NSMutableArray subclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, nsmutablearray, jsonmodel

I'm going crazy with this problem but i think the answer is easier than expected.
I have a class like this:

```
@protocol Messagge @end

@interface Messagge : JSONModel

@properties ..... ... ... ..

- (...) methods......
@end
```

i use this class for objects in a NSMutableArray i download as json from a webservice.
In another class like this:

```
@interface AnswerMessages : AJSONModelSubClass

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<Messaggio, ConvertOnDemand> *messaggi;

- (...) methods....
```

and everything seems to work fine with downloading an array using JSONModel `initFromURLWithString:` method on AnswerMessages.

But i need a change i'm not able to make it work.

I subclassed NSMutableArray for convenience and because i need to add methods and a delegate (i used a category but it was not enough now) so i created this classe:

```
@protocol MessaggesDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (...) delegateMethods......

@end

@protocol Messagges <Messagge,ConvertOnDemand> @end

@interface Messagges : NSMutableArray <Messagge, ConvertOnDemand>

- (....) methods....

@end
```

and tried to change AnswerMessages class like this:

```
@interface AnswerMessages : AJSONModelSubClass

@property (strong,nonatomic) Messaggi *messaggi;

- (...) methods.....
```

but now when i use `initFromURLWithString:` app terminates because:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Type not allowed', reason: 'Messagges type not supported for AnswerMessages.messagges'
```

So i tried some changes but none worked.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` ConvertOnDemand needs to use a different class behind the scene (i.e. you declare an NSArray property, but if you want it to convert dictionaries to models only when they are required it actually changes the property to another custom class).

In short `JSONModel` wasn't really tested to work with sub-classes of `NSArray`, so it might be easier for you if you just used an `NSArray` instead. Certainly ConvertOnDemand will not work with custom classes (you can also try to skip the "ConvertOnDemand") if you don't have too many items in the list.

Hope any of this helps!